# Linux make PHP from source to '.so' file

Tags: php, linux, makefile

I'm trying to 'make' PHP 5.5 on Ubuntu , but for my project I need call PHP cli interpreter like a build in module , like '.so' file, not executble. 
I can't find any information about it. The general question is " How to make correct <./configure > and < make >  commands to build PHP from sourse to '.so' files ? ".

I want to compile PHP source to '.so' file. 
It's possible from standard GCC compiler options but in PHP many virtual file paths and other hard codded parts in C files.
If anybody have experience in compiling PHP or other make project to '.so' files , please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: built into what? Usually you need to somehow connect the thing your building it for with whatever you're building. PHP is usually built stand-alone, or as a module for a SAPI such as Apache. There are configure commands to change the SAPI

Comment: When you now as usually building PHP from source you will have 2 php executble files 1 for CLI and one for CGI. I want to have 2 '.so' files like '.dll' files on windows.

Comment: Which extension do you need to compile from source? There are some which require installation of dependencies (like imap, xhprof, apc, memcache depending on the version of PHP you are using and the platform you are willing to build PHP or/and PHP extensions for)

Comment: <Which extension do you need to compile from source?> I'm compiling all PHP source and on output I want to have '.so' file NOT A STANDARD PHP EXECUTBLE

Comment: I might be wrong but compiled extensions can be found as *.so files for instance in `cli/lib/php/extensions/debug-non-?zts-20121212` after compiling from extensions source directories by following documentation provided below.

Comment: Yes your wrong :))  I don't want compile extensions. I want to compile all PHP source. Example when you compiling PHP in standard way you can execute it like `php script.php`. This is because you have executble in /sapi/cli/php directory. Now I want to have /sapi/cli/php.so file which I'll merge with my C++ project :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to follow the official documentation to install PHP from source or any of its extensions: https://raw2.github.com/php/php-src/master/INSTALL

I would otherwise recommend you to install PHP from package repositories.
In order to do so, you can use PPA with ubuntu by following instructions here for installing PHP 5.5:
https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5

Compiling extensions from source can be done by following instructions available from http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.phpize.php

Comment: First of all I don't want to install PHP I want to compile it but on output I want to have '.so' file for PHP CLI. I've looked in PHP configure file and there are no parameter for doing it. I'm just wondering if anybody have expreience of compiling PHP like module NOT STANDART EXECUTBLE

Comment: You might want to use phpize from the directory of an extension to compile from source. There, you could run `phpize .` and you could get away with it by running `configure --with-php-config=/path/to/php-config && make && make install` in best case scenarii (otherwise, you might want to run `./configure --help` after `phpize .`)

Comment: I've seen this documentation. http://php.net/manual/ru/install.pecl.phpize.php , This is not what I'm looking for.